# Desaturation CSS effect void when thumbnail text is hovered over

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like my thumbnail buttons to be desaturated when the text of the thumbnail is rolled over. Currently, I am calling my Wordpress post titles to appear when the Post Featured Image thumbnails are hovered over. When the thumbnail image itself is hovered over, the css effect works just fine. However, if I hover over the text of the thumbnail, the effect is broken. Is there a way around this?

```css
 .article-preview-image img:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
   -ms-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
   -o-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
   filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
   -webkit-transition: all .4s;
   -moz-transition: all .4s;
   -ms-transition: all .4s;
   -o-transition: all .4s;
   transition: all .4s;
 }
```

```html
<figure class="article-preview-image">
  <a href="http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/tara-temple/">
    <img width="190" height="189" src="http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/tarathumb.jpg" />
  </a>
  <h1 class="title">
                <a href="http://cks.whiterabbitstudio.us/tara-temple/">Tara Temple</a>
            </h1>
</figure>
```

If this isn't possible with CSS, I'm open to using javascript, but I don't know where to look for a simple tutorial or snippet. I'm not very familiar with java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct. Currently, you apply the effect to `img:hover`. Instead, you could apply it to an `img` located in a `.article-preview-image:hover`, like below.

```
img { /* Universal settings */
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}

.article-preview-image:hover img {
    /* When the article preview thing is being hovered, grayscale the image */
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:greyscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:greyscale(100%);
    -o-filter:greyscale(100%);
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your provided code didn't actually work, but your comment made sense, so I just swapped ".article-preview-image img" for "figure" and that did the trick. So, what ended up working was:
figure:hover {
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
    -moz-filter:grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
    -ms-filter:grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
    -o-filter:grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
    filter:grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
}

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the rollover text is not affected by the DIV overlay? It's supposed to be white, but the brightness effect drops it down to a gray color.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? In my experiment, the code I supplied did exactly that. We do not apply the grayscale effect to the `img:hover`, but instead apply it to the `img` located in `.article-preview-color:hover`.

Comment: Ah ha! OK, so you did nail it from the get-go. I just had a conflicting tag preventing me from seeing it perform. Thanks again! Please pay no mind to my previous "fix", it was no such thing!

Comment: No problem, always nice to have thoughtful feedback. I updated my answer to more clearly reflect how it works.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution:**

```
   .article-preview-image:hover img {
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:greyscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:greyscale(100%);
    -o-filter:greyscale(100%);
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: This is what I already have, right? Or am I missing something?